# Authorize Attribute not working when using authentication with Roles

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity

I am using decoration `[Authorize]` which is working fine for all the controllers from the project. Creating user as well as assigning roles to that user is working perfectly as well. 
Now, while accessing the roles assigned for that user, I got a strange error while calling `Roles.IsUserInRole` or `Authorize[(roles="ADMIN")]`.

The error is that, the page suddenly become non-responsive and after a while comes with a connection time-out error while establishing connection with the SQL Server.

The Authorize Attribute uses `AuthorizeAttribute` from `System.Web.Http`.

I don't believe if this really is a connection timeout issues as I don't have any issue while creating or assigning roles to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Aha, And here I find the exact solution for my problem. [MVC5 Authentication Roles Failure](http://blog.luppes.com/2013/12/08/mvc5-authentication-roles-failure/)

This is totally weired to see how adding `<remove name="RoleManager" />` fixed this. Thank you so much lluppes :). Though I have the solution, it will be great if anyone here can explain how this works.

Anyone who is wasting their time searching the solution, here is complete code that you need to add to Web.Config file.

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="RoleManager" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Hope, this helps.